# How do I keep multiple copies of Outlook in sync when using RPC over HTTP?

Tags: windows-7, exchange-2003, outlook-2007

I use Outlook 2007 at work with our Exchange 2003 server.  I just setup my home system with Outlook 2007 so that I could use the RPC over HTTP to access Exchange without having to use a VPN.

It works fine.  I can get mail, send mail, etc.  What it doesn't seem to be doing is staying in sync.  For example, I read a few messages at home, moved them into different folders from the Inbox, etc.  That all seemed fine.  When I login to my work machine and look at the copy of Outlook there, the mail is still unread and nothing has been moved.

Am I missing something simple here?  I would have to assume that my home machine should be telling Exchange where these messages belong and that they've been read.

Both machines are running Windows 7, if that matters.

Ideas?

Comment: OK, it appears that it has to do with the cached mode checkbox in the account settings.  When I turn that off it does keep them in sync.  Unfortunately, with that off things on my home system run MUCH slower too.  Does anybody know what the default settings for the caching are and would it eventually have "caught up"?

Comment: Mixing work e-mail with home software seems like a bad idea, and will probably lead to a question like this posted some day: http://serverfault.com/questions/146324/should-i-keep-my-ex-employers-data

Answer (score 0):

Check your send and receive settings. If you aren't connecting back to the exchange server frequently then the changes you are doing locally at home won't be reflected until the next time it connects.

Also make sure you have installed the latest Office 2007 Service Pack [SP 2 Currently](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953195) as that had a number of improvements for Outlook as per [Outlook 2007 improvements in the 2007 Office suite Service Pack 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968774/) and also the post Office 2007 SP2 Update for Outlook - [Outlook 2007 hotfix package (Outlook.msp): June 30, 2009](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970944) which mentions further performance improvements for Windows 7 RC.